# Why dismissing a UIAlertController calls dismiss on UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to understand why when dismissing a UIAlertController from a view controller presented in a navigation calls the `dimiss(animetaded:)` on the UINavigationController.

The reason is that I have inherited from UINavigationController to add some logic to when the navigation is dismissed but it is unintentionally called every time an alert is dismissed.

In my understanding the *presentingViewController* is responsible for dismissing a presented controller but it seems that this is not the case here.

What am I missing?

To reproduce, run then code below and it will log the message "DISMISS ON NAVIGATION".

```
    class RootViewController: UIViewController {
        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            present(alert, animated: true)
        }
    }

    class Nav: UINavigationController {
        override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
            print("DISMISS ON NAVIGATION")
            super.dismiss(animated: flag, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Now present the navigation controller from anywhere.

```
            let contrl = RootViewController()
            contrl.view.backgroundColor = .red
            contrl.definesPresentationContext = true

            let nav = Nav(rootViewController: contrl)

            present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Edit: Updated code to make *RootViewController* define a presentation context. 
Edit2: Update code to better represent the scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the navigation controller is the one who presents the alert controller even when you call `present` on your view controller. Same goes for the `dismiss` call.

If you want your view controller to present the alert set its `definesPresentationContext` property to `true`.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present...

> The object on which you call this method may not always be the one
>   that handles the presentation. Each presentation style has different
>   rules governing its behavior. For example, a full-screen presentation
>   must be made by a view controller that itself covers the entire
>   screen. If the current view controller is unable to fulfill a request,
>   it forwards the request up the view controller hierarchy to its
>   nearest parent, which can then handle or forward the request.

... and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621456-definespresentationcontext:

> When using the UIModalPresentationStyle.currentContext or
>   UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext style to present a view
>   controller, this property controls which existing view controller in
>   your view controller hierarchy is actually covered by the new content.
>   When a context-based presentation occurs, UIKit starts at the
>   presenting view controller and walks up the view controller hierarchy.
>   If it finds a view controller whose value for this property is true,
>   it asks that view controller to present the new view controller. If no
>   view controller defines the presentation context, UIKit asks the
>   window’s root view controller to handle the presentation.
>       The default value for this property is false. Some system-provided view controllers, such as UINavigationController, change the default
>   value to true.

**Update:**

For your specific problem (if I understood correctly) maybe it's the best solution to keep the presentation logic as is (navigation controller presents) but instead add a check in the navigation controller's dismiss method:

```
override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    if !(presentedViewController is UIAlertController) {
        // your additional logic
    }
    super.dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, but even after updating the code (see question edit) the behavior is the same. The dismiss is called on the navigation.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your view hierarchy... Can you explain a bit more what it is like? There is a `Nav` navigation controller that contains the `RootViewController` vc? What about the `ViewController` class then? Except of that you have to set `definesPresentationContext` to `true` for the view controller that **presents**. Not the one that **is presented**.

Comment: Its a *UINavigationController* with *RootViewController* as its root. The *RootViewController* presents the *UIAlertController*. The *ViewController* here can be any controller that presents the navigation. Will update de code to represent it better.

Comment: @MarcelodeAguiar Updated my answer.

Comment: Even though this solves the immediate problem it does not explains why the erratic behavior so I'm not marking this as the answer yet. Thank you.

Comment: @MarcelodeAguiar No, but my initial answer does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185622/discussion-between-andre-slotta-and-marcelo-de-aguiar).